# Resolving object in state of ui-router with ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Having really big JSON object in Angular controller and ui-sref link I want to pass this object to controller of template that would be in ui-view.
I know, that I can pass parameters to state with ui-sref, but I don't want this object to appear in address bar. Also, I know that we can use 'resolve' option in state, but I can't find how to pass data to 'resolve' function from link.
**Update**
If I use $state.go like that:
**router configuration**

```
state('social.feed.detailed',
     url: '/:activityID'
     templateUrl: 'views/social/detailedactivity.html'
)
```

**in template**

```
<ums-social-activity ng-repeat="record in SOC_FEED_CTRL.records"
     activity="record"
     ui-sref-active="selected"
     ng-click="SOC_FEED_CTRL.goToDetailed(record)">
</ums-social-activity>
```

**in controller**

```
$scope.SOC_FEED_CTRL.goToDetailed = (activity) ->
     # here activity is real object
     $state.go('social.feed.detailed', {'activityID':activity.id, 'activity':activity})
```

Then 'activity' param doesn't resolves at all.
**Update 2**
If I modify route configuration to this:

```
state('social.feed.detailed',
    url: '/:activityID?activity'
    templateUrl: 'views/social/detailedactivity.html'
)
```

Then activity is string "[object Object]"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ui-router` module's `$state.go` function call to manually pass in `$stateParams` that won't appear in the URL.  So, rather than using the `ui-sref` attribute, you'd set an `ng-click` handler that calls `$state.go(STATE,{'param':JSON})`.

Then, inject `$stateParams` into your controller, and read

```
$stateParams.param
```

To get your JSON object back.

Comment: That's what it should do if you alert it.  What happens if you `console.log` it?  You should be able to see your data.

Comment: Strange. If I annotate param in routes config, it resolves as "[object Object]" (possibly should use JSON.stringify) and display this "[object Object]" in address bar. If I doesn't annotate param in url of state it doesn't resolves at all.

Comment: No, I checked it with debugger. It's really string "[object Object]".

Comment: Then you clobbered it somewhere earlier.  The `$state.go` method doesn't alter the second parameter before it gets put into `$stateParams`.  What are you seeing if you `console.log(JSON)` before the call to `go`?

Comment: Anyway, it seems that $state.go doesn't prevent address bar to reveal passing parameters. So, I think I should switch to directive. But, also, I should say, that $state.go was a very good approach.

Comment: I tried it too and the data always gets converted to "[object Object]" so `state.go()` is NOT a feasible way to pass an object unless you want to stringify the object and then parse it on the other side.

Comment: An issue on UI-Router to help track this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/400#issuecomment-24177090

Comment: So, the take away form this comment thread is that this method will not work?

If so, can we please have it unticked, @mkrakhin?

Comment: No, this method is really working, but it doesn't do precisely what I want: resolves objects, but care them into address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are

```
    ui-sref-active="selected"
```

Selected represents an object

```
selected.name
```

or

```
selected.id
```

Selected looks like it represents a key value relationship.  That is what I am experiencing anyway.

```
<a ui-sref="itinerary.name({name:person.id})">
```